# A oneToMany join in Grails using findAll or HQL

Tags: grails, join, hql, grails-orm

I'm new to Groovy and HQL querying but I can't find a solution to this anywhere so it's driving me nuts.

I have two Domain classes which have a one to many relationship defined (a user can have many companies) and I effectively need to do (what would traditionally be called) 'a table join' but clearly with objects.

The classes go like this:

```
class User {
    transient springSecurityService

    static hasMany = [company: Company]

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

... and the company class

```
class Company {
    static scaffolding = true

    String name
    String address1
    String address2
    String address3
    String address4
    String postCode
    String telephone
    String mobile // mobile number to receive appointment text messages to
    String email // email address to receive appointment emails to  

    static hasMany = [staff: Staff]
    static belongsTo = [user: User]

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Gorm has created an `user_id` field within the company table but any attempt to use this in a query returns an error.

So how would I do something like:

`select * from user u, company c, where u.id = c.user_id;`

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can effectively use `join` on the association something like:

**HQL**
`select * from User as u inner join fetch u.company as companies where u.id = ?`

Note that using `fetch` in the query would eagerly fetch the associated collections of `companies` for a `user`

**findAll()**

```
User.findAll("from User as u inner join fetch u.company as companies where u.id = ?", [1])
```

Benefit of using `findAll` instead of HQL is that you can easily implement pagination something like:

```
User.findAll("from User as u inner join fetch u.company as companies where u.accountExpired = true", [max: 10, offset: 5])
```

To get a concrete implementation and really understand things in details I would insist to have a look at [findAll](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html) and [HQL associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).

Comment: thank you for such a well formed and useful reply. Your response was most helpful in resolving this problem.

Comment: @user2181809 Glad it was helpful. You can make it helpful to others by accepting the answer.